# QLineEdit to accept only one character/digit

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I want to have a `QLineEdit` that accepts only a character or digit . Is there a possibility to set it like in html an input to have a `maxlength` ? I mean to do this from the constructor of `QLineEdit` ?

I don't need something complicated ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is exactly like you wanted it to be. `QLineEdit` has the `maxLength` property. You set it either using the property system, or using the setter method:

```
QLineEdit le;
le.setMaxLength(1);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't need someting complicated ...

Unfortunately, it's couldn't be called easy solution, but you should be advised about [QRegExpValidator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexpvalidator.html).

Usage example:

```
#include <QRegExpValidaor>
#include <QLineEdit>
...
...
QRegExp rx ("\\w");
QRegExpValidator * v = new QRegExpValidator (rx, this);
QLineEdit * le = new QLineEdit (this);
le->setValidator (v);
```

Comment: I hoped there was a way to reduce the space of writting in the QLineEdit ... it seemed more elegant.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Qt, so may be more elegant way exists.

Comment: Thank you for the usage example ! If I won't find any other way,I'll use it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the alternate way to limit line edit input to one character/digit:

```
QLineEdit le;
le.setInputMask("N");
le.show();
```

For more details on input mask usage refer to the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop).